# Can a prime in a Dedekind domain be contained in the union of the other prime ideals?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $R$ is a Dedekind domain with a infinite number of prime ideals.  Let $P$ be one of the nonzero prime ideals, and let $U$ be the union of all the other prime ideals *except* $P$.  Is it possible for $P\subset U$?

As a remark, if there were only finitely many prime ideals in $R$, the above situation would not be possible by the "[Prime Avoidance Lemma](http://commalg.wiki-site.com/index.php/Prime_avoidance_lemma)", since $P$ would have to then be contained in one of the other prime ideals, leading to a contradiction.

The discussion at the top of pg. 70 in Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory" motivates this question.

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
According to [Claborn's theorem](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/leedhamgreen.pdf)<sup>1</sup> any abelian group is the class group of some Dedekind ring.
Take a Dedekind ring $R$ whose class group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and freely generated by  the ideal $I$. Since $I=\mathfrak m_1 \mathfrak m_2\ldots \mathfrak m_N$ with all $\mathfrak m_i$'s maximal, one of those maximal ideals, call it $\mathfrak m$, must be without torsion. I claim  that $\mathfrak m$ is contained in the union of the other maximal ideals of $R$.
Indeed, take an arbitrary nonzero $f\in \mathfrak m$ and decompose $(f)$ into a product of primes :
$$(f)=\mathfrak m^r.\prod \mathfrak n_i^{r_i}$$  (  $\mathfrak n_i\neq \mathfrak m, \quad $almost all $r_i=0$)
You can't have all the $r_i=0$, else $(f)=\mathfrak m^r$ would imply that $\mathfrak m$ is torsion in the class group.
Since $f$ is  in *all* the maximal ideals  $\mathfrak n_i$  with $r_i\neq0$ , the claim is proved : $\mathfrak m$ is contained in the union of the other maximal ideals of the Dedekind ring $R$.

**An easy warm-up**  John (rightfully) evokes the prime avoidance theorem. It is  easy to see that this theorem doesn't hold for infinitely many primes. For example consider   the product ring $R=\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$ and the maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_n=\{(q_i)\in R |  q_n=0\}\subset R$ . Then for the ideal  $I=\mathbb Q^{(\mathbb N)}$ of almost zero sequences we have $I \subset \bigcup \mathfrak m_n$ although $I\nsubseteq \mathfrak m_n$ for each $n$.
This easy counterexample doesn't answer John's actual (more precise and more demanding) question .

**Thanks**  to Jyrki who accurately pointed out (in a now tactfully deleted comment!) that my previous version incorrectly assumed that in Claborn's theorem I could take primes as free generators of the class group .

**A mistake in a book** (added later)  In the book  [*Algebraic Number Theory*](http://books.google.com/books?vid=9783642084737) mentioned by John in his question the author describes (on page 66) a generalized localization. He starts with a completely general commutative ring $A$ and a completely arbitrary set $X\subset\text{Spec}(A)$ of prime ideals of $A$. He remarks that the complement $S=\text{Spec}(A)\setminus \bigcup \{\mathfrak p|\mathfrak p\in X\}$ is a multiplicative set and considers the ring of fractions $A(X)=S^{-1}A$. He writes that the only primes  $\mathfrak q\subset A$ that survive in $A(X)$ are those which are subsets  $\mathfrak q\subset \bigcup \{\mathfrak p|\mathfrak p\in X\}$, and this is absolutely correct. However he adds that in the case of a Dedekind ring $A$ the surviving ideals are those $\mathfrak p \in X$ . This claim (repeated page 70) is not true, as shown by taking for $A$ our $R$ above and for $X$ the set of all maximal ideals in $R$ different from $\mathfrak m$: that ideal $\mathfrak m$ survives in $R(X)$ although it is not an element of  $X$ : $\mathfrak m \notin X $ by the very choice of $X$.
Congratulations to John for catching this very subtle little mistake made by a great arithmetician in a great book.

<sup>1</sup> C. R. Leedham-Green: *[The class group of Dedekind domains](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/leedhamgreen.pdf)*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 163 (1972), 493-500 ; [doi: 10.1090/S0002-9947-1972-0292806-4](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1972-0292806-4), [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1995734).

Comment: Georges - Many thanks for your help.  The discussion in Neukirch (pg 70) seems to tacitly assume that above is not possible, so I really appreciate your clarification!

Comment: Unfortunately, this small problem also invalidates his Proposition (11.6) (pg 70) without some further hypotheses to rule out cases like the above.  The sequence would not then be exact, or even a chain complex.

Comment: You are right, John: the mentioned  mistaken result in the book unfortunately seems to be actually  used in the Proposition you quote .

Comment: @Georges: I find it interesting that you link to a paper of Leedham-Green on my website which gives the *second* published proof of Claborn's Theorem.  You could also have linked to Claborn's original proof: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/claborn66.pdf.  Alternately, I myself have a soft spot for the third published proof: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/ellipticded.pdf.

Comment: Dear Pete, I hadn't realized that the paper was from your website: I just quickly googled and linked to the first paper that was freely accessible. But I am very happy that  it comes from your site. Just between you and me, I have never read a proof of that theorem but I'll certainly  have a look at yours and at Claborn's. (I read the statement a long time ago in a book by Fossum and it stuck since I found it quite unexpected).

Comment: Dear Georges, very nice answer! In fact you showed that for any Dedekind domain whose class group is not torsion (not necessarily equal to $\mathbb Z$), there is an example as required. As an explicit example (that you certainly known!), if $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb C$ and $P$ is a point of infinite order, then the maximal ideal of $R:=O_E(E\setminus \{\infty\})$ corresponding to $P$ has infinite order in the class group of $R$.

Comment: Dear @QiL, thanks for your interest. Yes I have known  the example with elliptic curves since my complex analysis days. I found the contrast with the holomorphic case astonishing: on a non-compact Riemann surface all holomorphic vector bundles (of any rank) are trivial, and  in particular GAGA fails in a spectacular way for affine curves.

Comment: In this case $R$ is the ring of integers in some number fields, is the result on Proposition (11.6) (pg 70) even true?

Answer (score 21):

If $R$ is the ring of integers $O_K$ of a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbf{Q}$, then I don't think this can happen. The class of the prime ideal $P$ is of finite order in the class group, say $n$. This means that the ideal $P^n$ is principal. Let $\alpha$ be a generator of $P^n$. Then $\alpha$ doesn't belong to any prime ideal other than $P$, because at the level of ideals inclusion implies (reverse) divisibility, and the factorization of ideals is unique.

This argument works for all the rings, where we have a finite class group, but I'm too ignorant to comment, how much ground this covers :-(

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer: Jyrki would obviously have completely solved the question had he known (remembered?) Claborn's theorem.

Comment: @Georges: Thanks. You're too kind. My exposure to Dedekind domains is limited to number rings and the simplest coordinate rings. I had never heard of Claborn's result. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 14):

This answer refers to the contributions of Jyrki and Georges: assume that a maximal ideal $P$ of a Dedekind domain $R$ is NOT contained in the union of all other maximal ideals. Then there exists an element $f\in P$ such that $v_P(f)=n>0$ for the discrete valuation attached to $P$ and $v_Q(f)=0$ for all $Q\neq P$. Now $P^n$ consists of those elements $r\in R$ such that $v_P(r) \geq n$. Thus for every $r\in P$ we get $r=fs$ with $s\in R$. Hence $P^n =fR$. Jyrki has already shown that if $R$ has torsion class group, then no maximal ideal contained in the union of all others can exist.

So: a maximal ideal of $R$ contained in the union of all other maximal ideals exists if and only if the class group of $R$ is not torsion.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  Note also that the condition that the class group be torsion is also equivalent to every ring intermediate between $R$ and its field of fractions is a localization: see e.g. $\S 22.2$ of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf.  (When I get the chance, I may add the result of this answer to this section: it is interesting!)

Comment: @Georges: there is indeed a little typo in Hagen's answer: it should say $P^n = \{r \in R \ | \ v_P(r) \geq n\}$ [edit: I took the liberty of fixing this].  But then if you have an element $f \in P^n$ with valuation exactly $n$ at $P$ and zero at every other prime, it must indeed generate $P^n$.  To restate what Hagen and Jyrki have shown: a maximal ideal $P$ in a Dedekind domain is *not* contained in the union of all other maximal ideals iff the class of $P$ has finite order in $\operatorname{Pic} R$.

Comment: Thanks to Pete for his answers to my ( now deleted) questions.  I'm upvoting Hagen this minute.

Comment: @Georges: OK, then I guess now is the time to tell you that I *already* updated my notes to include this discussion.  (See pp. 254-255.)

Comment: Dear Pete, I think your notes are great because they are not contained in the union of all the other books on commutative algebra :-)