# Proof of direct sum of ideal class group of Neukirch book

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

[image]

In books Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory.

I don't understand.

1) Why there exists $a$ such that $a\equiv c \ \mod \mathfrak p $ and $a\in ca_{\mathfrak p}^{-1}a_{\mathfrak q}$ for $\mathfrak q\neq \mathfrak p$?

2) Why $\epsilon=ac^{-1}$ is a unit  in $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p}$?

Please.

Thanks you all-.

Comment: These proofs can be pretty hard to read.  I think it's easier to think about propositions like this in terms of valuations.  For example, for which each prime $\mathfrak p$ you get a valuation $\nu_{\mathfrak p}$ on $K$ for which $\mathcal O_{\mathfrak p} = \{x \in K : \nu_{\mathfrak p} \geq 0\}$.  See Cassels and Frohlich, Algebraic Number Theory the first chapter for slicker proofs.

Answer (score 0):

I asked exactly the same question two years ago: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471378/j-mathcalo-cong-bigoplus-mathfrakp-p-mathcalo-mathfrakp-for-on). 
Also see my comment to the answer, which explains $(2)$. 
Hope this helps.