# Counterexample of prime avoidance with infinite case

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

The Prime Avoidance Theorem is :

> Let $I \subset R$ be an ideal (with $R$ commutative ring) and $I \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^r P_i$, where each $P_i$ is prime. Then $I \subseteq P_i$ for some $I$.

I want to find counter example of this does not hold in the case there are infinitely many prime ideals.

I often see this example in the case of $R=\Bbb C[x,y]$, but I want to find an example in the case $R$ is **Dedekind domain**.

Any good ideas ?

I tried with ring of integers of number field, but in vain.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems like it would follow from unique factorization of ideals.

Comment: A quick search yields https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05496

Comment: This yields a counterexample for Dedekind domains: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51362/348926